# Glassfish 4.0 Security Exception at ClassLoader

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, compile-time-weaving

My setup consists of Glassfish 4, a MySQL database, Eclipse-Link 2.5 as JPA provider. In order to profit from lazy fetching and load groups, I statically weave my entity classes.

Now I get the following error while starting my stand-alone client:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeavedRest"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

The libs in my classpath are (among others):

- gf-client.jar
- security.jar
- javaee-api-7.0.jar
- eclipselink.jar

Somebody any idea how to solve the security exception ?

Many thanks in advance - kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish use the OSGi bundles for EclipseLink, not the eclipselink.jar.  This may be related to the issue, trying adding the same bundles to your client that you server is using, not the eclipselink.jar.